# Fifa 17 two button controls

Tags: ps4, fifa-17

Fifa 17 on ps4 offers three control modes. Classic, alternative and two buttons. I switched between classic and two buttons and felt like there was no difference between classic using two buttons and two buttons playing with two buttons. Are there any differences?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

When using the classic or alternative control modes, there is a specific button for

- Shooting (Circle with the classic control mode)
- Short passes (Cross)
- Lob passes (Square)
- Through balls (Triangle)

These can be modified depending on whether you're attacking or defending, your position on the field, whether R1 or L1 are held, etc.
When using the two button control mode, the four actions listed above are reduced to two actions: Shooting and passing.

Comment: So how can I trigger different passes with two button control?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can trigger a lob shot with L1+Circle, but I don't think that you can trigger through balls.